# SQL 2008 Management Studio-- where to find table relationships?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm brand new to SQL Server 2008, and have some newbie questions about the diagram pane.  I just dragged two tables onto it to do an inner join, and the console "knew" to create a one-to-many relationship between them.  Where is this information kept in the Management Studio for me to look at closer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the tables has a foreign key referencing the other table.  In Object Explorer, expand the information for the tables involved and look under Keys.

Answer (score 2):

Much of this information is actually available in system tables in the database containing the user tables.

Here are two of the available tables of interest. **sys.tables** contains table information, **sys.foreign_keys** contains relationship information via foreign key constraints.

[sys.tables (Transact-SQL) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx)
[sys.foreign_keys (Transact-SQL) @MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx)

Also handy is the following information on Pinal Dave's site on using this information for your own lookups.

[Find tables with Foreign Key Constraint in Database @ SQLAuthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/04/sql-server-2005-find-tables-with-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/)
[Find Relationship of Primary key and Foreign Key using T-SQL @ SQLAuthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/26/sql-server-2008-find-relationship-of-foreign-key-and-primary-key-using-t-sql-find-tables-with-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/)